# Multiple Parameters Report Builder

Tags: parameters, reportbuilder

I have a parameter in my report which allows the user to select multiple values from a dataset.

Is there anyway that I can add the selection that the user has made to the report body?

Example if the user has selected values 1 and 2. Can I not get the report to state that when the user ran the report they select these particular values?

I added a place holder to the parameter on the report and it errors on multiple selection  - but works on one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this by doing the following -

=Join(Parameters!Department.Value, " , ")